# Ajax function not returning any html

Tags: ajax

I'm trying to develop an Ajax process in a Drupal Module. Here's the code :

```
function My_Module_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['route/to/ajax/%'] = array(
    'page callback' => '_MY_MODULE_processing',
    'page arguments' => array(3),
    'type'  => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'access arguments' => array('acces content'),
    'delivery callback' => '_MY_MODULE_listing'
  );

  return $items;
}

function _MY_MODULE_processing($region='110') {

  // Executing some operations to retrieve a list of NIDs
  // retrieving the nodes
  $nodes = node_load_multiple ($nidList);
  return ($nodes) ;
}
/**
 * Here is the templating part
 * @param unknown $nodes
 */
function _MY_MODULE_listing ($nodes){
  $build = array();
  $nodeList='';
  foreach ( $nodes as $node ) {
    $nodeList = $nodeList.'<option value='.$node->nid.'>'.$node->title.'</option>';
  }
    $build['content'][]=array(
      '#prefix'=>'',
      '#suffix'=>'',
      '#markup'=>$nodeList,
    );

  return ($nodeList);
}
```

I don't get any response with this. I've run debugging function and it goes inside every function. First `_MY_MODULE_processing` then `_MY_MODULE_listing`.

How can i return a correct response ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. I returned the answer with [ajax_deliver](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!ajax.inc/function/ajax_deliver/7) :

```
function mij_add_aide_list_proposition($nodes){
    // Magic stuff goes here (construction of $nodeList)
    $build['content'][]=array(
      '#prefix'=>'',
      '#suffix'=>'',
      '#markup'=>$nodeList,
    );

  //$test=drupal_render($build);
  ajax_deliver($build);
}
```

If someone finds another way, I'm open to any change !